# Issues in filtering rows using np.where

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign values to rows where a condition is verified (`True/False`).

```
for i in range(0,3):

new_dataset=df[str(i)][df[str(i)]["Current Amount"] != "3m"]
  for i in range(0,3):
    df[i]['Value'] = np.where(df[i]['Amount']== True, 100, 50)
```

where `i` can span from `0` to `3`. `Value` is the new column that I would like to create; `Amount` is a column already existing in the original dataframe. In the first part, I create new dataframes filtering rows having current amounts equal to 3 million.

However I got the following error:

```
   /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
    A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
    Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

    See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
      after removing the cwd from sys.path.
```

I have tried to follow the steps suggested in this post: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas), but it seems that it is still continuing to be not clear to me how to fix the issue.

Could you please help me to fix the issue? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: u shouldnt set a value equal to True. i dont think that would work

Comment: without equal to True it has not been working, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is not used solution without `[i]` and compare by `True` if column is boolean?

```
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Amount'], 100, 50)
```

EDIT: Here is necessary [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
new_dataset=df[str(i)][df[str(i)]["Current Amount"] != "3m"].copy()
```

Comment: Because I am considering many dataframes and I am trying to do this using a for loop statement, instead of doing it one by one.

Comment: @still_learning - OK, is possible get 3-5 rows of your code before error?

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you for your help. Let me know if you need more code. The columns are boolean in all the dataframes (I used `astype('bool')` to convert them at a certain point)

Comment: could you please explain me why I need to use .copy()? Does it create a list of dataframes or multiple dataframes too?

Comment: @still_learning - If you modify values in `new_dataset` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.